# Install SBT without internet connection

Tags: sbt, predictionio, xsbt

I am trying to use prediction.IO in a machine that can't be connected to the internet. When I try to build, it wants to download the dependencies of SBT. I want to know how this can be done manually, and if there is a place from where I can down download all the dependencies, and run SBT.

I would really appreciate any help. I am dying out here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy your sbt project to computer connected to internet
2. Run `sbt test:compile` task
3. Copy and pack `$HOME/.sbt` `$HOME/.ivy2` directories (`%USERPROFILE%\.sbt` `%USERPROFILE%\.ivy2` for windows 7/8/10)
4. Copy this folders to the same location in your destination computer.
5. Run your build with `sbt "set offline := true" <task>` or add to your sbt file `offline := true`